# No boot in partition problem after ext3 format

Tags: boot

I had a Win 7 64bit and 10.04 dual boot. However, a friend mistakenly formatted the Ubuntu partition with my partition software (Paragon Partition Server 10) and after a restart i was greeted with a black screen 'no boot partition'. My question now is how do i recover my Win 7 boot loader and install 11.04 when it drops. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many possibilities :

- using the Win7 install via command
  line to set it or use SystemRescueCD : but you'll lose data
- editing your grub conf
- etc

Select among your preferences :

**the fastest** 
 simply reinstall your ubuntu to have your grub2 refreshed.

**the smartest** 
 a good option is to learn

You may edit the /boot/grub/menu.lst file in any text editor, and change the line which says:

> default 0

to the number of your choice. Grub counts from zero, so the first item in the grub menu is 0, second is 1 etc etc. The little 'Other Operating Systems:' dividor in Grub DOES count as a menu item too, so don't forget to include it in your count

You will need to use sudo or gksudo to gain root priveleges in order to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst, so you should press alt+f2 then in the box, type:

> gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

Answer (score 1):

Boot up with your Ubuntu CD, you should be able to access your windows 7 partition.

Plug in an external hard drive and back up your data from win7 to external hard drive.

Then find a win7 CD and use the repair tool. 
You should be able to re install the windows boot fairly easily following instructions if you get a CD somewhere.

But back up your CD above all. It's your priority right now.

Comment: Sorry meant your data is your priority.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the windows install cd, choose the recovery console option, and run the FIXMBR command.